# How to include the Draco decoder in a library that uses three.js?

Tags: three.js, vite

I'm making an npm package that uses a draco 3d model and I would like to have the draco decoder as part of the library, since having content hosted elsewhere would make the library unusable in an offline environment.

I'm using Vite, so I tried specifying the decoder path like so:

```js
loader.setDecoderPath(new URL("./assets/", import.meta.url).href);
```

which doesn't work, since the required files are not included in the built folder.

Then I configured Vite to copy files to the `dist` folder with a plugin:

```js
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    ...
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: "src/draco/*",
          dest: "draco"
        }
      ]
    }),
  ],
  ...
})
```

```js
loader.setDecoderPath(new URL("./draco/", import.meta.url).href);
```

but this still doesn't work, since the loader looks for files on the given path relative to the URL of the website that's using it.

I'm getting

```
http://localhost:5173/draco/draco_wasm_wrapper.js responded with 404: Not Found
```

which is understandable, since the running website that has my library installed wouldn't host all of the contents of the library on it's root.

Question is how do I deal with this?
Best solution would be if I could pass a file to the draco loader instead of a path containing files, then I could base64 encode the decoder in the url, but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: Did you try to use it as a dependecy?

I never tried it before, but check the doc here: https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript/npm/draco3d